# Confidence Interval of lmer model producing NA

Tags: r, lme4

`NA` is occurring for confidence interval of lmer model ? How can I get rid of it ?

```
simfun <- function(J,n_j,g00,g10,g01,g11,sig2_0,sig01,sig2_1){
     N <- sum(rep(n_j,J))  

     x <- rnorm(N)         
     z <- rnorm(J)         

     mu <- c(0,0)
     sig <- matrix(c(sig2_0,sig01,sig01,sig2_1),ncol=2)
     u   <- rmvnorm(J,mean=mu,sigma=sig)

     b_0j <- g00 + g01*z + u[,1]
     b_1j <- g10 + g11*z + u[,2]

      y <- rep(b_0j,each=n_j)+rep(b_1j,each=n_j)*x + rnorm(N,0,sqrt(0.5))
     sim_data <- data.frame(Y=y,X=x,Z=rep(z,each=n_j),group=rep(1:J,each=n_j))

  } 


noncoverage <- function(J,n_j,g00,g10,g01,g11,sig2_0,sig01,sig2_1){
    dat <- simfun(J,n_j,g00,g10,g01,g11,sig2_0,sig01,sig2_1)
    fit <- lmer(Y~X+Z+X:Z+(X||group),data=dat,control=lmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=20000)))

   ci=confint.merMod(fit,oldName=FALSE,c("sd_(Intercept)|group","sd_X|group","sigma"))

    ci.u0 = as.numeric(ci[1,])
    nc.u0 = ifelse((ci.u0[1]<sqrt(sig2_0) & ci.u0[2]>sqrt(sig2_0)),0,1)

    ci.u1 = as.numeric(ci[2,])
    nc.u1 = ifelse((ci.u1[1]<sqrt(sig2_1) & ci.u1[2]>sqrt(sig2_1)),0,1)

    ci.e = as.numeric(ci[3,])
    nc.e = ifelse((ci.e[1]<sqrt(0.5) & ci.e[2]>sqrt(0.5)),0,1)

    nc = data.frame(nc.u0=nc.u0,nc.u1=nc.u1,nc.e=nc.e)

  }

 fit <- replicate(10,noncoverage(10,5,1,.3,.3,.3,(1/18),0,(1/18)))

 fit
, , 1

  nc.u0 nc.u1 nc.e
 1 0     0     0   

 , , 2

  nc.u0 nc.u1 nc.e
 1 0     0     0   

 , , 3

 nc.u0 nc.u1 nc.e
1 1     0     0   

, , 4

 nc.u0 nc.u1 nc.e
1 NA    0     0   

 , , 5

  nc.u0 nc.u1 nc.e
1 0     NA    0   

, , 6

 nc.u0 nc.u1 nc.e
1 1     0     0   

 , , 7

 nc.u0 nc.u1 nc.e
1 0     0     1   

 , , 8

  nc.u0 nc.u1 nc.e
1 0     0     0   

 , , 9

 nc.u0 nc.u1 nc.e
1 0     0     0   

, , 10

 nc.u0 nc.u1 nc.e
1 0     NA    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here (which has been fixed in the development version of `lme4` ...) is that likelihood profiles are constructed using spline fits.  If the profile is too flat, the spline fit will fail.  The development version now tries to substitute linear interpolation in this case.

```
simfun <- function(J,n_j,g00,g10,g01,g11,sig2_0,sig01,sig2_1){
    N <- sum(rep(n_j,J))  
    x <- rnorm(N)         
    z <- rnorm(J)         
    mu <- c(0,0)
    sig <- matrix(c(sig2_0,sig01,sig01,sig2_1),ncol=2)
    u   <- MASS::mvrnorm(J,mu=mu,Sigma=sig)
    b_0j <- g00 + g01*z + u[,1]
    b_1j <- g10 + g11*z + u[,2]
    y <- rep(b_0j,each=n_j)+rep(b_1j,each=n_j)*x + rnorm(N,0,sqrt(0.5))
    sim_data <- data.frame(Y=y,X=x,Z=rep(z,each=n_j),
                           group=rep(1:J,each=n_j))
} 
set.seed(102)
dat <- simfun(10,5,1,.3,.3,.3,(1/18),0,(1/18))
library("lme4") ## version 1.1-9
fit <- lmer(Y~X+Z+X:Z+(X||group),data=dat)
pp <- profile(fit,"theta_",quiet=TRUE)  ## warnings
cc <- confint(pp)  ## warning
##            2.5 %    97.5 %
## .sig01 0.0000000 0.2880457
## .sig02 0.0000000 0.5427609
## .sigma 0.5937762 0.8802176
```

You should also note that these confidence intervals [are based on ML, not REML, fits](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/325) ...

Comment: Is lme4_1.1-9 available ? how can I get it ?

Comment: `devtools::install_github("lme4/lme4")` (you need to have Rtools/compilers installed)

Comment: I can't install lme4_1.1-9. It gives error : `> devtools::install_github("lme4/lme4")
Downloading github repo lme4/lme4@master
Installing lme4
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.3/bin/i386/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/training/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpA5VSYn/devtools2845e963ba/lme4-lme4-45cb62a"  \
  --library="C:/Users/training/Documents/R/win-library/3.1" --install-tests`

Comment: `* installing *source* package 'lme4' ...
** libs
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="lme4.dll" OBJECTS="external.o glmFamily.o mcmcsamp.o optimizer.o predModule.o respModule.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'lme4'
* removing 'C:/Users/training/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/lme4'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/training/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/lme4'`

Comment: `Warning in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\training\Documents\R\win-library\3.1\00LOCK-lme4-lme4-45cb62a\lme4\libs\i386\lme4.dll to C:\Users\training\Documents\R\win-library\3.1\lme4\libs\i386\lme4.dll: Permission denied
Error: Command failed (1)
`

Comment: Not sure whether this is a permissions problem (as suggested from your third block) or a compilation problem.  Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141982/inline-function-code-doesnt-compile/23608198#23608198 ?

Comment: I am not understanding how does `profile` working? sometimes it's giving  54 values for each column, sometimes 48.  What is `.zeta` in it ? `pp <- profile(fit,"theta_",quiet=TRUE)` giving values for every random and fixed effects, but `cc <- confint(pp)  ` producing confidence interval for only variance-components. Why ?

Comment: in `?profile` documentation, I didn't get the option `quiet`. Why is to specify `quiet=TRUE` in `profile` ?

Comment: Is there any advantage of doing` confint(profile(fit,"theta_",quiet=TRUE))`, rather doing `confint(fit)` ?

Comment: can you ask these questions either as a new StackOverflow question or on `r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org` ... ?

Comment: I asked those questions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944611/profile-for-mermod-objects-lme4