# Difficulty to construct profile confidence interval in lmer model

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, mixed-models, random-effects

When I fit lmer model with my data , there is no warning message. But when I tried to construct confidence interval by `confint` , it shows the following warning message :

```
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : non-monotonic profile
2: In nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
 Last two rows have identical or NA .zeta values: using minstep
3: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : non-monotonic profile
```

Is there any way to overcome the warning message , that is, is there any argument(option) which can remove the problem ? I have used the argument `control=lmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=20000))` :

```
fit <- lmer(Y~X+Z+X:Z+(X||group),data=dat,control=lmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=20000)))
```

Comment: Most likely, your model is not identifiable, so without data you will not get a good answer. And the double || confuses me. Are you sure? As a minor point, not relevant to the question, X + Z +X:Z can be written as X*Z.

Comment: @DieterMenne yes, I am sure about `||` as the covariance between random intercept and random slope is zero.

Comment: It helps to have your questions self-contained.  I think there is probably simulation/replication code for this in a previous question.  Can you either link to it or (preferably) copy the code to make this example reproducible?

Comment: @BenBolker please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796299/confidence-interval-of-lmer-model-producing-na

Comment: @BenBolker and in that link , I found only this three warning message when I run the code for the combination `fit <- replicate(1000,noncoverage(30,20,1,.3,.3,.3,(1/18),0,(1/18)))` . for other combination such as `fit <- replicate(1000,noncoverage(30,5,1,.3,.3,.3,(1/18),0,(1/18)))` , I get more than 50 warning message.