# Different lme4 version is giving different result

Tags: r, lme4

I am facing a problem in `lme4` package that seems very strange to me .

`R` version  3.0.2 (2013-09-25) and  lme4_1.1-7 behaves differently with `R` version  3.2.1(2015-06-18) and lme4_1.1-8 . For example , in  `R` version  3.0.2 , if I ran the code `confint.merMod(fit, oldName = FALSE, "sd_(Intercept)|group")` , it gives the following error :

```
Error in confint.merMod(fit, oldName = FALSE, c("sd_(Intercept)|group", : for method='profile', 'parm' must be specified as an integer -
```

But such error does not occur in `R` version  3.2.1 and lme4_1.1-8 .

Again in lme4_1.1-7 , `confint` command produces result , but with the same data `confint` returns `NA` in lme4_1.1-8  .  Why ?

Is the result valid that I am getting from `confint` command in  lme4_1.1-7 ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @Pascal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796299/confidence-interval-of-lmer-model-producing-na is the example , that I use for the judgement between two version of lme4

Comment: I'm confused about what *is* working in 1.1-7; is it just `confint(fit)` (i.e., it works if you get the confidence intervals for all parameters) ?

Comment: @BenBolker yes, before knowing your answer , I tried `confint(fit)` in 1.1-7, as I didn't know how is to do that only for variance components. So in 1.1-7 `confint(fit)` returned me confidence intervals for all parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the less difficult part of your question (why do you get an error in 1.1-7 and not 1.1-8): specifying the parameter by name rather than integer should work in 1.1-8 but *not* in 1.1-7. [This commit from June 13](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/commit/c791045870478daabb7fe5b51fd25bbb9e9aeaf5) shows when the feature was added to the package.

The following code works in the most recent development version of `lme4` and should work in 1.1-8 (but *not* 1.1-7): we can specify the parameter to profile by number, by new name, by old name, or we can specify that we want to profile all of the random-effects parameters (there is only in one in this case):

```
library("lme4")
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction~Days+(1|Subject),sleepstudy)
p1 <- profile(fm1,parm=1) 
p2 <- profile(fm1,parm="sd_(Intercept)|Subject",oldName=FALSE)
p3 <- profile(fm1,parm=".sig01",oldName=TRUE)
p4 <- profile(fm1,parm="theta_")
```

If you need to work with 1.1-7 the workaround should be simple: just specify the parameter by number.

Comment: But why does 1.1-7 produce result when 1.1-8 returns `NA` for same data ?

Comment: without a minimal reproducible example there is no way for me to know.

Comment: In this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796299/confidence-interval-of-lmer-model-producing-na , I set the seed as `set.seed(851406)` and `fit <- replicate(1000,noncoverage(30,5,1,.3,.3,.3,(1/18),0,(1/18)))` . lme4_1.1-8 produces `NA` whereas lme4_1.1-7 produces numerical value. In  lme4_1.1-7 , I wrote  `ci=confint(fit)` .

Comment: Do I really need `replicate(1000,...)` to see the problem? One replicate takes 1-2 seconds on my machine, so this will be tedious. Please edit your question to make it *self-contained* and *minimally* reproducible ...

Comment: If I do `replicate(50,...)` with version 1.1-9 (I know you're still having trouble installing) I don't get any `NA` values.  This may also be platform-specific; if this goes on we may need to see the results of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Perhaps in lme4_1.1-8 , if you replicate it only  50 or 100 times, you will get `NA`.

Comment: At last, I have installed lme4_1.1-9. Thanks a lot.