# Profile for merMod objects (lme4)

Tags: r, lme4

I am not understanding how does `profile` work in lmer ? Sometimes it gives exactly same number of values as total number of observations, and sometimes fewer or higher than total number of observations. Also what is `.zeta` in the output of profile?

(2) Again

```
pp <- profile(fitted,"theta_",quiet=TRUE)#fitted is a fitted model
```

is giving values for every random and fixed effects, but

```
cc <- confint(pp)
```

is producing confidence interval for only variance-components. Why ?

In `?profile` documentation, I didn't get the option `quiet`. How does `quiet` work ?

(3) Is there any advantage to run the command

```
confint(profile(fitted))
```

rather than running `confint(fitted)` .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give a reproducible example:

```
library("lme4")
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction~Days+(Days|Subject),sleepstudy)
```

> Sometimes it [`profile`] gives exactly same number of values as total number of observations, and sometimes fewer or higher than total number of observations.

I'm not sure what that means.

> Also what is `.zeta` in the output of profile?

The `.zeta` column is the signed square root of the difference from the minimum deviance.

Specifying no value for `which` (`profile`) or `parm` (`confint`) profiles/gives CIs for all parameters; specifying `"theta_"` only gives results for random effects variance-covariance and residual variance (if any).

```
## all parameters (random and fixed)
pp0 <- profile(fm1)                 
levels(pp0$.par)
## [1] "Days"        "(Intercept)" ".sig01"      ".sig02"      ".sig03"     
## [6] ".sigma"     
# random effects only
pp1 <- profile(fm1,which="theta_")
levels(pp1$.par)
## [1] ".sig01" ".sig02" ".sig03" ".sigma"
```

Similarly for `confint()`:

```
## all parameters
cc0 <- confint(pp0)
rownames(cc0)
## [1] ".sig01"      ".sig02"      ".sig03"      ".sigma"      "(Intercept)"
## [6] "Days"
## random-effects parameters only
cc1 <- confint(pp1)
## [1] ".sig01" ".sig02" ".sig03" ".sigma"
```

The `quiet` parameter is for `confint()` (not `profile()`).  By default, applying `confint()` *directly to a fitted model* issues a message

> Computing profile confidence intervals ...

to warn the user that a computationally intensive/slow process is taking place.  Using `quiet=TRUE` suppresses this message.

The *Note* in `?confint.merMod` says:

> The default method ‘"profile"’ amounts to
>       `confint(profile(object, which=parm), signames=oldNames, ...), level, zeta)`
>       where the ‘profile’ method ‘profile.merMod’ does almost all the
>       computations.  Therefore it is typically advisable to store the
>       profile(.) result, say in ‘pp’, and then use ‘confint(pp,
>       level=*)’ e.g., for different levels.

In other words, if you are going to want to do anything else with the profile information (plot profiles, or compute confidence intervals for more than one alpha-level) it is more efficient to compute the profile and store it, rather than repeatedly computing the profile.  If all you want are the default 95% confidence intervals then you might as well use `confint(fitted_model)`.

Comment: May be in the first question he meant this : The the number of rows of pp0 is 117. But the number of rows in the data frame is 118. Is it possible to explain what is the meaning of this 117 ?