# Break loop with keyboard input (R)

Tags: r, while-loop, rstudio

I need an R loop to continue running until the user presses a key. Something like the below. Any ideas? I'm new to R

```
while(FALSE_after_user_input){
  queryWebApi()
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

**EDIT 1**

What I'm really after is a way to stop data collection. I have a function I want to run every few seconds to query new data. The user needs the ability to stop the data collection loop.

readline() doesn't work as it halts execution of the data collection loop

Comment: Another option is to catch an interrupt, either Ctl-C or the Rstudio stop button. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63190034

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Suggestion 1:** [TCL/TK](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/break-loop-with-keypress-td4695056.html)

```
library(tcltk)
win1 <- tktoplevel()
butStop <- tkbutton(win1, text = "Stop",
  command = function() {
    assign("stoploop", TRUE, envir=.GlobalEnv)
    tkdestroy(win1)
})
tkgrid(butStop)

stoploop <- FALSE
while(!stoploop) {
    cat(". ")
    Sys.sleep(1)
}
cat("\n")
```

Some code borrowed from: [A button that triggers a function call](http://www.sciviews.org/recipes/tcltk/TclTk-button-to-trigger-function/).

**Suggestion 2:** Non-blocking checking on standard input.  (Please be warned: `C` is not my core competence, and I cobbled this together from bits on the internet.)  The main idea is to write a function in `C` that waits for user input, and call it from `R`.

Snippet below adapted from [Non-blocking user input in loop](http://cc.byexamples.com/2007/04/08/non-blocking-user-input-in-loop-without-ncurses/). Save the following code as `kbhit.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <R.h>

void kbhit(int *result)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    fd_set fds;
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds); //STDIN_FILENO is 0
    select(STDIN_FILENO+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    *result = FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);
}
```

Then, from the command line, run `R CMD SHLIB kbhit.c` to compile it for `R`.

Finally, in `R`, load the newly created `kbhit.so`, write a function (`kbhit`) that returns the output from the `C` function, and then run your loop.  `kbhit()` returns 0 unless it receives the enter key.  Note that the only way to stop the loop is by hitting enter/return (or a hard break) -- if you want a more flexible approach, see the link above.

```
dyn.load("kbhit.so")

kbhit <- function() {
    ch <- .C("kbhit", result=as.integer(0))
    return(ch$result)
}

cat("Hit <enter> to stop\n")
while(kbhit()==0) {
    cat(". ")
    Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

[More details on the `.C` interface to `R`](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~rpeng/docs/interface.pdf).

**On a Windows machine:**

kbhit.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <R.h>

void do_kbhit(int *result) {
    *result = kbhit();
}
```

In `R`:

```
dyn.load("kbhit.dll")

kbhit <- function() {
    ch <- .C("do_kbhit", result=as.integer(0))
    return(ch$result)
}

cat("Hit any key to stop\n")
while(kbhit()==0) {
    cat(". ")
    Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

P.s. I hacked this together through Googling, so unfortunately I don't know how or why it works (if it works at all for you!).

Comment: Thanks @WeihuangWong Is there a way to do this without a GUI? TCL/TK is GUI library, correct? If worse comes to worse I can use a GUI with a stop button.

Comment: the compiler isn't happy. I added `#include <sys/time.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>` and now I'm getting the following errors `undefined reference to `_imp__select@20'
undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet@8'`

Comment: Are you running Windows? I've seen examples that use the `kbhit` function in `conio.h`, that might work for you.

Comment: I'm on a Windows machine. Can you provide an example of using conio.h? I'm a C#/JavaScript developer by trade, I haven't touched C in years.

Comment: See edits.  I haven't used a Windows machine in ages, and have next to no knowledge of C, so this is kind of the limit to how much I can help you. But I've tested the code above and it works (Windows 10).  Good luck!

Comment: It compiles! but it's stuck in the loop. I'm on windows 10 as well.

Comment: FYI, I'm also having to use [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141982/inline-function-code-doesnt-compile) to compile every time I open RStudio.

Comment: How are you running the script?  I opened up R from the command prompt, `source`d the R script, and it breaks on keypress.  I'm not sure if it will work if you are using RStudio or some other sort of setup.

Comment: I was trying to run it through RStudio. I'm going to mark your answer as correct, I've negotiated the requirement so I no longer need to implement it. Thank you for your help @WeihuangWong