# Continue running code if user input is not given

Tags: r

I apologyse in advance if the question is a bit unclear!

I created a for-loop that generates a plot every 0.1 seconds (to simulate a video of a moving object). The code works smoothly, but I would like to allow the user to pause and resume the "video" when he/she wants to inspect in more detail one of the video frames.

I thought about reading an input from the console using readline() or scan() functions at the end of the loop. For example, the user types "p"+enter to pause the video. However, readline() would expect an input at the end of each iteration. In my case, the user would only provide an input in some of the iterations, so the loop must continue running when no input is given.

This would be a simplified version of the loop (printing a value in the console instead of plotting an image):

```
for(index in c(1:10)){
  print(index)        # In my script it generates a plot
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
  input = read.line() # If user types an input in the command, execution is paused
                      # If no input is given, the loops continues with the next iteration
 ...
 ...
}
```

Do you have any ideas/suggestions of how to deal with this?
Thanks :)

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38757455) answer?

Comment: Thanks for the link. The TCL/TK approach is very interesting (I did not manage to compile the C file in approach 2).In the beginning I made a mistake that drove me crazy. My plotting script is packed in a function so that the user can just write custom_function(name_data_file) and generate the plots. With this design the buttons were not responding. After some trial and error I realised that the variable _stoploop_ is defined inside the function, and it cannot be controlled with the buttons (they control the general environment but not the variables inside the function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this using `library(shiny)` to provide a pause/resume button could work:

```
ui = fluidPage(
  actionButton("pause", "Pause"),
  plotOutput("myplot")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(i = 0, go = TRUE)
  maxIter = 1000
  timer = reactiveTimer(100)
  
  output$myplot = renderPlot({
    x = seq_len(1000)
    y = sin(x/20 + rv$i) * cos(x/50 + rv$i/2)       
    plot(x, y, type = "l", main = rv$i, ylim = c(-1,1))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$pause, {
    rv$go = !rv$go 
    updateActionButton(session, inputId = "pause",
      label = c("Resume", "Pause")[rv$go + 1L])
  })
  
  observeEvent(timer(), {
    req(rv$i < maxIter)
    req(rv$go)
    rv$i = rv$i + 1
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```